# Subtracting from a UInt in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, types, type-conversion, .net-micro-framework

I've got a function which needs to take a `UInt` as a parameter. `I'm using the .Net Micro Framework`

As a simple example, I'd like to do something like:

```
        Dim x As UInteger
        For x = 0 To 100
            Port.SetDutyCycle(x)
            Thread.Sleep(10)
        Next
        For x = 100 To 0 Step -1
            Port.SetDutyCycle(x)
            Thread.Sleep(10)
        Next
```

The second `For` won't compile as `-1` can't be represented as a UInt. So next I tried...

```
        For y As UInteger = 0 To 100
            Port.SetDutyCycle(100 - y)
            Thread.Sleep(10)
        Next
```

This won't compile as the `- y` forces a conversion to Long which then can't be narrowed to UInt. Next attempt:

```
            Port.SetDutyCycle(DirectCast(100 - y, UInteger))
```

The `100 - y` won't compile as "Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'UInteger'"

So... How can I easily get a UInteger that decrements from 100 to 0 in a loop?

As Per Hans Passant's answer, the 2nd code block works perfectly in vanilla .Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to declare y.  Fix:

```
    For y As UInteger = 0 To 100
        Port.SetDutyCycle(100 - y)
        Thread.Sleep(10)
    Next
```

---

The warning is generated because you have non-standard compile settings.  Project + Properties, Compile tab, Warning configuration section.  The normal setting for the "Implicit conversion" option is None.  Leaving it set to Warning is fine, you just need to make the conversion explicit:

```
        Port.SetDutyCycle(CUInt(100 - y))
```

Comment: Try it in VS - there's a warning on Line #2 `Implicit conversion from Long to UInteger`. I'm using the .Net Micro Framework which may be causing the problem? I'll try it in vanilla .Net4

Comment: Hmmm it does work in vanilla .Net4 - apologies I didn't think that would be significant. I'll update the Q